# Add a single user to local group through GPO

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

I want to add a *single* domain user in local admin group via GPO. I know about restricted groups, but it only allows to add domain groups, and not a domain user.
Is it possible to do so, without creating unnecessary groups ?

Comment: `I know about restricted groups, but it only allows to add domain groups, and not a domain user`. Where are you getting this bogus information? That is not accurate. Any named principal may be added to a Restricted Group policy or a Group Policy Preferences Groups policy.

Comment: Yes, a user can be added to a Restricted Group policy; however, only in a sense of being a member of a locked membership - it cannot be used to merely add a user to the group.  GP Preferences is spot on.